# Rotative CustomSwitches does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

I'm using Rotativa.MVC 2.0.3 in my MVC5 project.  I keep getting an error in the code editor stating "ActionAsPDF does not contain a definition for CustomSwitches".  I tried using ViewAsPDF as shown in the links below also, same result.
Here are a couple of sources I found regarding how to add headers/footers to Rotativa PDFs:

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1006319/Using-Rotativa-in-MVC-Application)

[CSharpCorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0ef46a/using-rotativa-in-mvc-application/)

The code in my controller is:

```
using Rotativa.MVC;

public ActionResult CertificatePDF(int? wo_nbr)
{
    var PDFresult = new ActionAsPdf("Certificate", new { wo_nbr = wo_nbr })
    {
        FileName = "Certificate.PDF",
        CustomSwitches = "fill in details later"
    };
    return PDFresult;
}
```

So the question is:  How do I implement CustomSwitches in Rotativa 2.0.3?  Or, where is the CustomSwitches definition?  The PDF renders terrifically without the CustomSwitches tag, so I know Rotativa is doing it's job.

Answer (score 1):

While looking for something else, I stumbled across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475890/cannot-print-asp-net-mvc-5-2-2-view-in-rotativa-mvc-2-0-3) that answered my question.

Basically, I had to reference Rotativa.Core and create a DriverOptions object.

Here is what the working code looks like:

```
using Rotativa.MVC;
using Rotativa.Core;

        public ActionResult CertificatePDF(int? wo_nbr)
        {
            string CustomSwitch = "--footer-line --footer-font-size \"8\" --footer-left \"Printed: \"" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var rotativaOptions = new DriverOptions() { CustomSwitches = CustomSwitch };
            var PDFresult = new ActionAsPdf("Certificate", new { wo_nbr = wo_nbr })
            {
                 RotativaOptions = rotativaOptions
            };
            return PDFresult;
        }
```

Again, I'm using Rotativa 2.0.3.  Hope this answer helps someone else!